# C++ Lookup table for derived classes

Tags: c++, types, derived-class, base-class

I have a wrapper class holding a bunch of derived class objects by means of a vector of references to a common base class. During runtime, the Child objects are created based on user input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>


class Base {
 public:
  virtual void run() = 0;
};

class Wrapper {
 public:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> blocks;

  template <class Child>
  auto create() -> std::shared_ptr<Child>
  {
    auto block = std::make_shared < Child > ();
    blocks.emplace_back(block);
    return std::move(block);
  }

  template <typename A, typename B>
  void connect(A a, B b)
  {
    using connectionType = typename A::element_type::out;
    connectionType* port = new connectionType;
    a.get()->ptr_out = port;
    b.get()->ptr_in = port;
  }
};

class Child_1 : public Base {
 public:
  using in = int;
  using out = float;
  out* ptr_out;
  in* ptr_in;
  void run() { std::cout<<"running child 1\n"; *ptr_out = 1.234;};
};

class Child_2 : public Base {
 public:
  using in = float;
  using out = bool;
  out* ptr_out;
  in* ptr_in;
  void run() { std::cout<<"running child 2\ngot: "<<*ptr_in; };
};

int main () {

  Wrapper wrapper;
  /* read config file with a list of strings of which types to create */
  std::vector < std::string > userInput;
  userInput.push_back("Type 0");
  userInput.push_back("Type 1");

  for (auto input:userInput)
  {
    if (input == "Type 0")
      wrapper.create < Child_1 > ();
    else if (input == "Type 1")
      wrapper.create < Child_2 > ();
    /* and so on */
  }

  /* read config file with a list of pairs of which objects to connect */
  std::vector < std::pair < int, int >>connections;
  connections.push_back(std::make_pair(0, 1));

  // e.g. user wants to connect object 0 with object 1:
  for (int i = 0; i < connections.size (); i++)
  {
    auto id0 = connections[i].first;    // e.g. 0
    auto id1 = connections[i].second;   //e.g. 1

    // this will not work because Base has no typename in / out:
    // wrapper.connect (wrapper.blocks[id0], wrapper.blocks[id1]);

    // workaround:
    wrapper.connect(
        std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Child_1>(wrapper.blocks[id0]),
        std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Child_2>(wrapper.blocks[id1]));
  }

  wrapper.blocks[0].get()->run();
  wrapper.blocks[1].get()->run();

  return 0;
}
```

Now, I'm only able to store a vector of Base objects which cannot hold the different in/out types of each derived object. **When I want to connect the derived objects (which are stored as Base class objects), I need to dynamic_pointer_cast them back into their derived class. What's the most efficient way to do this?**

There are a few ways I could think of - none of which seem to be possible (to my knowledge) with C++:

- Have some kind of lookup-table / enum which returns a type to cast to; I could then create a map from the user input "Type 0" etc to the type and cast accordingly.
- Have some kind of lambda-like expression that would return the correctly casted pointer type such that I can call `wrapper.connect( lambda_expression(...), lambda_expression(...) )`.
- Brute force: check for each possible combination of user inputs and call the connect function with the dynamic_pointer_cast (as shown in the coding example). This will very likely not be suitable for my real-world application (currently using about 25 such classes) because it would result in a huge number of not maintainable function calls...
- Somehow give the generic in/out types to the Base class but I can't think of any method to do so.

I really hope I'm missing something obvious. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't like `dynamic_cast` myself.  It doesn't scale well.  My preferences is to declare pure virtual methods in the base class as necessary and then override these in the child class(es) to suit.

Comment: How would I use a pure virtual function in that case? I need to call the templated connect function from the wrapper based on the derived classes type definition.. I would need some kind of virtual member variable whose type is defined by the derived class.

Comment: `return std::move (block);` can simply be `return block;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a typical case of double dynamic dispatching, however there is a possible simplification in that the output and input types must match. Hence, here is sort of a half-Visitor pattern.

First, we extract the concepts of input and output types into classes so that they can be targeted by `dynamic_cast`:

```cpp
template <class In_>
struct BaseInput {
    using In = In_;
    std::shared_ptr<In> ptr_in;
};

template <class Out_>
struct BaseOutput {
    using Out = Out_;
    std::shared_ptr<Out> ptr_out;
};
```

Note: I've swapped in `std::shared_ptr`s rather than letting raw owning pointers in the wild.

From there, we can declare a virtual `connectTo` function in `Base` to get the first level of dynamic dispatching:

```cpp
class Base {
    public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void run() = 0;
    virtual void connectTo(Base &other) = 0;
};
```

Note: I have added a virtual destructor to `Base`. AFAICT it is superfluous thanks to `std::shared_ptr`'s type erasure, however Clang was spewing warnings at me and I wasn't willing to chase them down.

Finally, the second dynamic lookup can be done from `Base::connectTo`'s override, which I have factored out in a handy template:

```cpp
template <class In, class Out>
struct Child
: Base
, BaseInput<In>
, BaseOutput<Out> {
    void connectTo(Base &other_) override {
        // Throws std::bad_cast if other_'s input type doesn't match our output type
        auto &other = dynamic_cast<BaseInput<Out> &>(other_);
        this->ptr_out = other.ptr_in = std::make_shared<Out>();
    }
};
```

At that point a Visitor pattern would swap the objects around and perform a second virtual call from `other_` to get the second dynamic dispatch. However, as mentioned above, we know exactly what type we're looking for, so we can just `dynamic_cast` to reach it.

Now we can implement `Wrapper::connect` as simply:

```cpp
  template < typename A, typename B > void connect (A a, B b)
  {
    a.get()->connectTo(*b.get());
  }
```

... and define child classes this way:

```cpp
class Child_1 : public Child<int, float> {
public:
  void run() { std::cout<<"running child 1\n"; *ptr_out = 1.234;};
};
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SamhKf2gVXM7k5kX)

Comment: That works great, thanks a lot. Is the `override` necessary since it's a pure virtual function anyways? Or is it good practice?

Comment: @Dominic it's good practice. It would work just the same without it, but this ensures that the function actually is overriding something.